# Receiving Error "Foreign key must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key" despite not using composite keys

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpa

Running a project with the following classes fails with:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key
>   (FK9ex9b0501jh788ukls6wuglix:a_bc [bc_id])) must have same number of
>   columns as the referenced primary key (bc [b_id,c_id])

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "A_BC",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "BC_ID"))
    private Set<BC> set;
}

@Entity
public class B {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "BC",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "C_ID"))
    private Set<C> set;
}

@Entity
public class C {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "BC",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "C_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID"))
    private Set<B> set;
}

@Entity
public class BC {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")
    private B b;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "C_ID")
    private C c;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "A_BC",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "BC_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID"))
    private Set<A> set;
}

@Entity
public class A_BC {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")
    private A a;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "BC_ID")
    private BC bc;
}
```

Entities B, C and BC work as expected. B and C are connected to one another using BC as a join table.

The problem arises when introducing the entity A and asociating it with BC. BC acts as a join table but it's also a part of another join table (A_BC), I think this is what is causing the error, but I don't see why or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have a @OneToMany on one side and @ManyToMany on the other.

Comment: I don't have any '@OneToMany' relationships, just '@ManyToOne' and '@ManyToMany', and no cyclic references.

Comment: you  should use many-to-many in both class.... one side Many-to-one references create this problem...

Comment: Could you please update your answer with any changes to the entities necesary to make it work?